# Multiple column join

Tags: sql, join, ms-access-2010

I have two tables: `data` and `structure` that I am attempting to query to return a recordset with all columns from `data` and a single columns from `structure`. I cannot seem to get the joins figured out. This will be performed in Access 2010, and all fields are strings.

`data` contains, among other things, three columns: `Country`, `State`,  and `City`. `structure` also contains these three columns, as well as a storeID. There is a many to 1 relationship if one was to concatenate Country, State, City between `data` and `structure`. I need the query to select all fields from `data` and a new column for `storeID`. Ideally the `storeID` would be in `data` already, but that is unfortunately out of my control.

`data` looks like

```
Country   State   City   Value
US        FL      MIA    1.0
US        FL      MIA    2.1
CA        BC      VAN    0.8
MX        CH      JUA    1.2
```

`structure` looks like

```
Country   State   City   storeID
US        FL      MIA    4522
CA        BC      VAN    3866
MX        CH      JUA    8985
```

would like the query to return

```
Country   State   City   Value  storeID
US        FL      MIA    1.0    4522
US        FL      MIA    2.1    4522
CA        BC      VAN    0.8    3866
MX        CH      JUA    1.2    8985
```

Comment: You need to use a `LEFT JOIN` to join your tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple conditions in a JOIN clause: separate them with boolean operators, just as you would in a WHERE clause (AND, OR, etc.).  Your goal is to have all conditions evaluate to TRUE or FALSE, but within that range you can do quite a lot.

In your specific case, it's fairly simple - use the Country, State, and City columns from both tables to make the connection. I've set up some sample data in the query below:

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (Country VARCHAR(2), State VARCHAR(2), City VARCHAR(3), Value DECIMAL(2,1))
DECLARE @Structure TABLE (Country VARCHAR(2), State VARCHAR(2), City VARCHAR(3), StoreID INT)


INSERT INTO @Data (Country, State, City, Value) VALUES ('US', 'FL', 'MIA', 1.0)
INSERT INTO @Data (Country, State, City, Value) VALUES ('US', 'FL', 'MIA', 2.1)
INSERT INTO @Data (Country, State, City, Value) VALUES ('CA', 'BC', 'VAN', 0.8)
INSERT INTO @Data (Country, State, City, Value) VALUES ('MX', 'CH', 'JUA', 1.2)


INSERT INTO @Structure (Country, State, City, StoreID) VALUES ('US', 'FL', 'MIA', 4522)
INSERT INTO @Structure (Country, State, City, StoreID) VALUES ('CA', 'BC', 'VAN', 3866)
INSERT INTO @Structure (Country, State, City, StoreID) VALUES ('MX', 'CH', 'JUA', 8985)


SELECT d.Country, d.State, d.City, d.Value, s.StoreID
FROM 
    @Data d
     LEFT JOIN 
    @Structure s ON 
        d.Country = s.Country AND
        d.State = s.State AND
        d.City = s.City
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT data.*, structure.storeID 
FROM data 
LEFT OUTER JOIN structure USING(storeID)`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT data.Country, data.State, data.City, data.Value, structure.StoreID
FROM data
LEFT OUTER JOIN structure USING(structure.StoreID)
```